# Как сделать сравнение строк на большие, меньшие?

Tags: c#

Как сделать сравнение строк (string) на большие или меньшие?

Мне нужно сделать что-то типа этого: if (fi1 >= fi2); if (fi1 <= fi2); if (fi1 == fi2) ...

```
private string GetFolderName(string filePath)
{
    using (var photo = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        try
        {
            photo.Flush();
            photo.Close();
            var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
            var fi1 = fi.CreationTime.ToString(_dirMask);
            var fi2 = fi.LastWriteTime.ToString(_dirMask);

            if (fi1 == fi2) //if (fi1 >= fi2) как это сделать?
            {
                return fi1;
            }
            else return fi2;
        }
        catch
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Длину строк или что? Пока ничего не понятно

Comment: А до перевода времени в строку не лучше было бы сравнивать, нэ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP как пример: fi1=11.10.11; fi2=09.11.12 мне нужно сделать сравнение этих дат. (11.10.11 < 09.11.12)

Comment: Ну тогда выкидывайте `ToString` и сравнивайте непосредственно `DateTime`

Comment: @Сергей нет. Нужен другой вариант

Comment: Сомнительно как-то звучит. А `_dirMask` - что за зверь такой?

Comment: Просто вам либо вручную посимвольно тогда сравнивать (сложно и стремно). Либо обратно в `DateTime` переводить (не вижу смысла)

Comment: @Сергей _dirMask это маска наименование папки. То есть есть возможность указать какая папку будет создаваться в процессе работы программы. В данный момент она создает папки с датами (YYYY;MMMM;DDDD) но есть возможность задать пользовательское создание папки ((D;MMM;YYYY) = (9;фев;2014)).
Я надеюсь вы поняли)

Comment: Все же не понимаю что вам мешает сравнивать даты до перевода их в строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем такое не устраивает?

```
private string GetFolderName(string filePath)
{
    using (var photo = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        try
        {
            photo.Flush();
            photo.Close();
            var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
            var fi1 = fi.CreationTime.ToString(_dirMask);
            var fi2 = fi.LastWriteTime.ToString(_dirMask);
            if (fi.CreationTime >= fi.LastWriteTime)
            {
               return fi1;
            }
            else return fi2;
        }
        catch
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Временно сделал так)

Comment: Почему временно? Это единственное правильное решение.